# How do i play audio on devkitPro?

Tags: c, wii, devkitpro

I am trying to develop a app that will use the devkitPro toolkit. How do I play Audio files on Wii?  I can't seem to get them to play. I have tried over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like this has been answered yet.

devKitPro is a beautifully documented platform, so hopefully you'll find these examples useful.

Check out:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/devkitpro/files/examples/wii/

Within that tarball, you'll find examples for playing .mod, .ogg and .mp3 files. You're best off testing your console with the MODPlayer first to ensure that it isn't a user-side issue (poorly installed dependencies) as the other file formats are much more complex [can't get much simpler than four channels].